# WPF ListView: Is it possible for rows to have subrows?

Tags: wpf, listview, treeview

I'm working on a WPF control that needs to be in the first instance a WPF listview. However, there's a complication: The objects viewed by the listview have child objects, so the user needs to be able to click to view children - which means that details of the children of a given item should appear below the listview row for that item (similar to a treeview, but there's only two levels). Is this possible? The children are a different datatype from the parent so the rows showing them don't form part of the listview itelf.

Visually, the effect looks like:

```
************ = a listview row for the a parent item
------------ = a row for the child item
+/-          = a 'treeview' expander

the UI should be
- ************
    ------------
    ------------
+ ************
+ ************
```

Any ideas? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this functionality only with the ListView control. Depending on the complexity of your 'subrows', you will need to extend the ListView's functionality. A good starting point can be this control: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeListView.aspx

Comment: Thanks Erez and Andrei. Two useful answers. Agreed, it does look like a treelistview is the way to go. And it also looks like there's a lot of treelistview controls to choose from. Evidently this scenario is one that a lot of people have encountered :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely TreeListView.
More resources (in addition to what Andrei Pana provided):

http://windowsclient.net/blogs/ricciolocristian/archive/2008/03/22/a-complete-wpf-treelistview-control.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/kb/wpf/wpf_treelistview_control.aspx